# Separate the content of WP_Query in 2 different pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing a code that update my custom fields. The problem is that when I use the parameter `'posts_per_page => -1`, the memory exceeds the limit and I get an error. Is there a way to separate the content of posts_per_page in maybe 2 different pages, with each page getting half of the content? I'm also accepting new ideas, I only need to find a way to update the custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

The `'posts_per_page => -1'` will load all posts. This could be the reason your memory limit is exceeding (depending on how many posts you have).

You could set a `'post_limits'` value to the argument to limit the amount, this can also be queried into different page/post templates to display the posts or post count you wish.

Example:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'       => 'price',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,

);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

The above query will load all posts from the 'Product' custom post type and display them on the page the function is called.

More examples: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/